# How I can detect roque T_SL (<<) using the linux terminal?

Tags: find

Whilst I was running `composer update` I got the following error:

```
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover

In Store.php line 18:
                                                               
  syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL), expecting end of file  
                                                               

Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Therefore, I am trying to detect the wrong file using bash:

```
cd ./myproject
find . --name Store.php
```

But how I can also filter the find result not only with the name bust with the roque characters `<<` as well? I other words I want to use both file contents and file name as find parameter in order to fine-grain filtering in `find` results.

Answer (score 1):

To examine file contents you need to combine `find` with a tool such as `grep`:

```
find . -name Store.php -exec grep -l '<<' {} +
```

Comment: Indeed, thanks @roaima!